# Using Gridview to display multiple items in cells

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm wanting to build a page using ASP.NET/C# and Webforms to create a page that displays essentially a grid of images/links/text.  Here's an example of what needs to be displayed.

```
 _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ 
| |img| | | |img| | | |img| | | |img| |
| |_ _| | | |_ _| | | |_ _| | | |_ _| |
|  txt  | |  txt  | |  txt  | |  txt  |
|_ _ _ _| |_ _ _ _| |_ _ _ _| |_ _ _ _|
 _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ 
| |img| | | |img| | | |img| | | |img| |
| |_ _| | | |_ _| | | |_ _| | | |_ _| |
|  txt  | |  txt  | |  txt  | |  txt  |
|_ _ _ _| |_ _ _ _| |_ _ _ _| |_ _ _ _|
```

The end result would be a 4x4 grid.  the img and txt fields would link to that items particular page.  The final product would have more content but for the gist of the idea an img and txt field works.

I started this as a table, but realized that I wanted better way of doing this.  I wanted something that would more easily have the itemds assigned/created.  I thought of a Gridview but didn't think that would work very well since I've only seen gridviews display database table contents exactly as they are in the DB table.  Each of the "cells" would contain a row of the DB table.

the DB table would look like this:

Content_table

```
Content_ID  Content_Image  Content_Title  Content_Txt  Content_Link
    1         "item1.jpg"     "Title1"      "Text1"     "LinkText1"
    2         "item2.jpg"     "Title2"      "Text2"     "LinkText2"
    3         "item3.jpg"     "Title3"      "Text3"     "LinkText3"
    4         "item4.jpg"     "Title4"      "Text4"     "LinkText4"
```

Now I would like to use the Gridview if it's possible to get this to work, I'm just not sure if it can.  If anybody has a better suggestion for what would more easily accomplish what I'm trying to do I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Create a User Control for your Image block; create a repeater and add this user control in your Item Template; write a CSS class for your image block so that it goes to next row when it reaches specific size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us say you have CSS like below

```
.pictureEntry { margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px; padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px; float: left; border: solid 1px #cccccc; width: 200px !important; height: 250px; font-size: 10pt; }
.pictureEntry .image { max-height: 150px; max-width: 100px; }
```

On your page add a literal control to dynamically build HTML and add it to the page

```
<asp:Literal ID="DirectoryItems" runat="server" />
```

On server side, build your HTML.

```
private void BuildContent(string locationId, string sortBy)
{
    var html = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var item in items)
        html.Append(GetPartialHtml(item));

    DirectoryItems.Text = html.ToString();
}

private string GetPartialHtml(BL.Model.Person person)
{
    var htmlTemplate = "" + 
        "<div class=\"pictureEntry\">" + 
            "<img src=\"##ImagePath##\" class=\"image\" />" +
            "</div>";

        htmlTemplate = htmlTemplate.Replace("##ImagePath##", "your file path");

        return htmlTemplate;
}
```

If you want only specific no of items per row, wrap this Literal control inside another DIV with a calculated width that allows your no of items